# Import-PfxCertificate without prompt?

Tags: powershell

I have a script which runs `Import-PfxCertificate`. I want it to be able to run automatically, but I am unable to do this because of this prompt:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically answer "Yes" or to not show the prompt at all? The prompt won't show if I add the `-Confirm` flag, but then I can't get that to automatically answer "Y", so is there any possible way to automatically run `Import-PfxCertificate`?

I tried a couple of simple approaches, none of which have worked:

1. Setting `$ConfirmPreference` to `None`
2. Trying `echo "Y" | Import-PfxCertificate ...`
3. Trying `Import-PfxCertificate ... -Confirm:$false`

Comment: Pretty sure this is because you are trying to import into the trusted root folder. Where are you trying to import the certificate to?

Comment: LocalMachine\My -- what I'm really trying to do is get SSL working in my containers, for development I have a script which sets up a self-signed cert, my issue is I want my code to be able to run this automatically when it's in development mode.

Comment: If I use `CurrentUser\My`, it also gives the same popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to how the certificate is generated and imported. My script was based off [this](https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/develop-locally-with-https-self-signed-certificates-and-asp-net-core), which:

- generates the certificate in `CurrentUser\My`
- imports the pfx certificate into `LocalMachine\My`
- imports the certificate into `CurrentUser\My`

If I modify the script to do everything in `LocalMachine\My` then I no longer get the prompt (in the OP I thought I was using `LocalMachine\My` but turns out I didn't look closely enough and didn't replace `CurrentUser\My` in a couple of places).